# Tetrahedra require octahedra; 5-cells require...?

Tags: geometry, discrete-geometry, tessellations

It's well known that equilateral triangles tessellate $\Bbb R^2$ but regular tetrahedra do not tessellate $\Bbb R^3$. However, in three dimensions, we can make a a tessellation if we are permitted to also use octahedra to "fill in" the gaps that the tetrahedra leave.

[image]

**Question:** What happens in four dimensions? Do the 'gaps' again form cross-polytopes? Is a single convex polytope even sufficient? As a stretch question, if we demand the polytopes to be regular, can any finite collection fill such a gap?

I'd love an answer to the question in general dimension, but I'd be satisfied for just four.

Comment: I'm pretty sure tesseracts tile $\mathbb R^4$.

Comment: No question about that. But I'm interested in 5-cells, which are the 4D analogues of triangles, as opposed to tesseracts which I've always heard of as the 4D analogues of squares.

Comment: I was answering whether any collection of regular polytopes filled $\mathbb R^4$.

Comment: Ach, that was a typo; thanks for catching it (unintentionally :P)

Comment: I like the question a lot! I am wondering what exactly it presupposes, however. If you gave me a pile of tetrahedron, my first instinct wouldn't be to use the configuration in the picture (and hope for nice gaps), but start sticking tetrahedra face-to-face. So, I personally would like to get to the bottom of what it means to configure $5$-cells analogously -- that way we can talk about the four-dimensional gaps. Although I guess if we're only allowed to translate, that question may answer itself...

Comment: pjs: Thanks! I encourage you to try to do your 3D construction; it doesn't work, but it's very subtle and actually going through it is quite instructive. I think the formalization I want is something like: take the laminated 4-lattice, place a 5-cell at the origin with edges along the vectors defining a fundamental domain, and act on this 5-cell by all lattice-preserving translations. Take all the points that are in the fundamental domain but not in any of the 5-cells; tell me about this region. In 2d this doesn't fill the plane, but the 'gaps' left are triangles so you don't need a new shape.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The figure you drew looks like a big tetrahedron, where you bisected each edge to cut off a smaller tetrahedron at each original edge, leaving the octahedron in the center.

This approach could be generalized to higher dimensions, and would not result in cross polytopes but in 4d leads to something with 10 cells, 5 of them octahedra and 5 tetrahedra, unless I'm mistaken.

That subdivision doesn't directly lead to a tiling of the space, however, unless you allow for filler polytopes of infinitely many different sizes, so you can combine larger simplices and then fill gaps between these again.